# change and refresh session data in Node.js and express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I'm using Node.js along with express-session and 
I've got this session data that holds the user information

```
req.session.user
```

now when the user updates the information, I set the session to the new data and then reload it

```
req.session.reload(function(err) {
req.session.user = user;
});
```

it should work but the req.session.user still shows the old information, why? :(
many thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing ``req.session.save()`` and that returns before you ``req.session.reload()``?

Comment: no I'm not doing any req.session.save() in my app, but it's so weird cause according to API the reload should do the trick, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are reloading before saving your change. Saving usually happens at the end of the request automatically. There is a test in session.js which [demonstrates that behaviour](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/test/session.js#L258-L284).

Using `req.session.reload()` reverts the changes that currently have been been made while processing the request ...

```
req.session.example = 'set on set_reload'
req.session.reload( function (err) {
    res.render('index', { title: req.session.example });
});
// next http get request
// req.session.example == value before the call above
```

Consider using the session like this

```
req.session.example = 'set on set';
res.render('index', { title: req.session.example });
// next http get
// req.session.example == 'set on set'
```

If you have a real reason for using `req.session.reload()` then this type of usage will give you the desired behaviour

```
req.session.example = 'set on set_save_reload';
req.session.save( function(err) {
    req.session.reload( function (err) {
         res.render('index', { title: req.session.example });
    });
});
// next http get
// req.session.example == 'set on set_save_reload'
```

Comment: thanks for the your answer but it still doesnt reload the session, let me explain it a little bit, I store the nickname of users in the session, but users can change the nickname, now when users change it, the session.user which holds the nickname has too change too but it doesn't so I need to manually reload it.

Comment: Don't reload unless you wish to undo any unsaved changes to the users session. Just assign the new value and ``session`` will save the value.

Comment: sorry for the delay and thanks for the help, I voted up as much as I could, It's the least I could do for your great answer